# Change multi categorical factor in R to binary

Tags: r, categories

I have an R factor in with 11 categories

```
> predictor <- factor(V14)
> summary(predictor)
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
1017   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20   20
```

I want to turn everything that is not 0 to 1.
So it should look like this

```
> summary(predictor)
   0    1     
1017   200
```

Comment: `levels( V14 ) [ which( levels( V14 )  > 0 ) ] <- 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to numeric:

```
predictor <- factor(+(!!V14))
summary(predictor)
#   0    1 
#1017  200
```

**Explanation**

The long way is `factor(as.numeric(as.logical(V14))`. When numbers are coerced to logical, any number that is not zero, coerces to `TRUE` and 0's will be `FALSE`. Then turning it back to numbers from logical, any `TRUE` will become `1`, and `FALSE` will be coerced to `0`.

**Data**

```
V14 <- c(rep(0, 1017), rep(1:10, each=20))
```

Comment: For eagle and a share of the lead in the Code Golf Open.